# Improper Riemann Integral and Lebesgue Integral coincide when...

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am stuck with the following problem:

$I$ is an interval of $\mathbb{R}$. If $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ locally Riemann-integrable (i.e, its restriction to every compact interval is Riemann-integrable). Then $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable if and only if the improper Riemann-integral of $|f|$ exist, and in these cases, they coincide.

I think that Monotone Convergece Theorem may be useful if one approximates $f$ with $f \chi_{A_n}$ with ${A_n}$ a sequence of compact sets in $I$, but I am not sure about that. So I would like to know how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not every compact set, every compact interval

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality that $I=(a,b)$ and consider $I_{n}=[a+1/n,b-1/n]$ for large $n$, assume that
\begin{align*}
(R)\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|dx
\end{align*}
exists in improper Riemann sense, then
\begin{align*}
\infty>(R)\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(R)\int_{I_{n}}|f(x)|dx,
\end{align*}
and so the Lebesgue integral of $|f|$ on $I$ that
\begin{align*}
(L)\int_{I}|f(x)|dx
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(L)\int_{I}|f(x)|\cdot 1_{I_n}dx\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(L)\int_{I_{n}}|f(x)|dx\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(R)\int_{I_{n}}|f(x)|dx\\
&=(R)\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|dx,
\end{align*}
note that the first equality is by Monotone Convergence Theorem and also that for compact interval, a function is Riemann integrable then it is Lebesgue integrable and the integrals coincide.

Comment: Is the way taking $I_n$ OK if $a=-\infty$ or $b=\infty$ ?

Comment: Yes of course, this is already included in OP question and in my answer.

Comment: Really? In the case, $I_n$ are not compact so they don't define the improper Riemann integral I think. Especially when $a=-\infty,b=\infty$ , $I_1=I_2=\cdots=I$.

Comment: In case that $I=(a,b)=(-\infty,\infty)$, take $I_{n}=[-n,n]$ for $n=1,2,...$, then argue with the same reasoning.